# jquery WaterMark Textbox blink on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, watermark

I want to use WaterMark for some of my textboxes on my input form. The issue is I have an auto postback dropdownlist as well and this causes my textbox watermark text to blink on postback.

Below is the sample version of the scenario:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            $("#txtEmail").watermark("Email Address");
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Email Invalid"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="One" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Two" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Three" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The reason for this behavior is because jquery watermark is client-side.

One workaround I found is [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1073683.aspx). The issue with that is I have to use WaterMarkTextBoxExtender of AjaxControlToolkit which I would like to avoid if possible.

Edited: I was wrong. The workaround above I pointed will not work.

So what I looking for is a work around for jquery watermark and postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my option is instead of using auto postback of dropdownlist, I will have to make an ajax call using jquery on dropdown change and update controls on my page with the returned data from ajax call.

I have tried this in a sample and my WaterMark doesn't blink. I hope that is it unless I come across any side-effects.

If anyone has other inputs / suggestions, I am going to leave this open for a while.